# MVC 5 asp.net Inside Foreach Each Sum Related Data from other table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, foreach

Models are ,

```
ModelA:

 public int AId       {get;set;}
 public float Amount {get;set;}

ModelB:
  public int   BId              {get;set;}
  public float RequestAmount    {get;set;}
  public int AId                {get;set;}
  public virtual ModelA ModelA  {get;set;}
```

now when i want to list the ModelA, there as many item in ModelB related ModelA
i want to calculate **RequestAmount**  and list in ModelA foreach list:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var modelA = db.ModelA.Include(c => c.ModelB);
        return View(modelA.ToList());
    }
```

this will be the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<test.Models.ModelA>


@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
        </td>
        <td>
            **Here need to calcut or SUM value from ModelB only related to this**
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Where you are stuck at?

Comment: i need to sum value from ModelB and show in each foreach row of ModelA

Comment: @Prajwal any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join both the collection and group the result and do a Sum, project the result to a new view model.

So create the view model first

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public int AId { set;get;}
  public float Total { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your action method,

```
var data = (from a in db.ModelAs
            join b in db.ModelBs on a.AId equals b.AId
                group b by a.AId into g
    select new MyViewModel { AId = g.Key, Total = g.Select(f=>f.RequestAmount).Sum() })

.ToList();
```

And of course now your view is strongly typed to a list of MyViewModel

```
@model List<MyViewModel>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <p>@item.AId</p>
  <p>@item.Total </p>
}
```

Another option is, you can add a collection of `ModelB` to the `ModelA` class.

```
public class ModelA
{
   public int AId       {get;set;}
   public float Amount {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<ModelB> ModelBs {set;get;}
}
```

and use the `Sum` extension method.

```
@model IEnumerable<test.Models.ModelA>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.ModelBs.Sum(x=>x.RequestAmount)
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

Comment: is `.Sum` extension available for non Enumerable type?

Comment: Fixed. Sorry. Thanks for catching @RajshekarReddy